# How to show only unique results in PHP foreach foreach?

Tags: php, foreach

I have this code to check whether some files exist in a WordPress website. If any files are found, the links to those files are to be displayed. This code works fine, but one problem is there. For some URLs It returns same links multiple times. 
How to solve this? Any help is highly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form method="get" action="">
        <p><input name="siteinfo" style="width:700px;" placeholder="www.example.com" required="required"/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Get files" id="qr-gn"></p>
</div>
</form>
<br/>

<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['siteinfo'])) 
{
$input = ($_REQUEST['siteinfo']);

// in case scheme relative URI is passed, e.g., //www.google.com/
$input = trim($input, '/');
// If scheme not included, prepend it
if (!preg_match('#^http(s)?://#', $input)) {
       $input = 'http://' . $input;
}
$urlParts = parse_url($input);
// remove www
$domain = preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $urlParts['host']);

$urls=array("https://www.".$domain,"http://www.".$domain,"https://".$domain,"http://".$domain);
$files=array("wp-login.php","license.txt","readme.html");
foreach ($urls as $url)
{
    foreach ($files as $fil)
    {
$ch = curl_init($url."/".$fil);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
// $retcode >= 400 -> not found, $retcode = 200, found.
curl_close($ch);
if ($retcode==200)
{echo "<a href='$url/$fil'>$url/$fil</a>"."<br>";}
    }
} 
}
?>
```

Comment: The only thing you supply to `foreach` in your code is an array you've generated yourself. What is the non-unique part? Everything you supply has been hardcoded by yourself.

Comment: Not 100% what you are doing, but once you get `if ($retcode==200)`, then you could use `break;` to stop looking further for this URL.

Comment: If "https //www.example[dot]com/readme.html" is found, then I don't want "http //www.example[dot]com/readme.html" to be displayed. That's what I mean by 'unique results'. I know using foreach will loop through every items in the array though.

Comment: Yes, I will try using ```break;```.